# What do smugglers earn?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars

The newest bounty hunter book at least has information on what bounty hunters earn for what job. Is there anything similar for smugglers somewhere about what they earn, and if so where can I find it?

Answer (score 9):

### Yes, on Fly Casual sourcebook

Just like the bounty hunter's sourcebook, [No Disintegrations](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/news/2016/9/14/no-disintegrations/), smugglers also got their own sourcebook, [Fly Casual](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/star-wars-edge-of-the-empire/products/fly-casual/).

Starting on page 72, we get a lot of **information about a smuggler's job**, how to find a smuggling work, how much you can get paid for each service and the type of cargo transported, modifiers that can be obtained by *negotiating* the payment, and what kind of problems we can expect when a smuggler fails to do his job.

The book also goes into **details about the problems** that smugglers face, like custom offices, bureau services, faking transpoder codes, and finally, more information about hyperspace travel and how to quickly go where you have to go.

The **Cargo Payout** is probably the most important table on that chapter, which goes like this:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
\mbox{Rarity}& \mbox{Restricted} & \mbox{Unrestricted}
\\\hline
\mbox{4-5} & \mbox{10%} & \mbox{5%}
\\\hline
\mbox{6-7} & \mbox{25%} & \mbox{10%}
\\\hline
\mbox{8-9} & \mbox{30%} & \mbox{25%}
\\\hline
\mbox{10} & \mbox{50%} & \mbox{30%}
\\\hline
\end{array}

That's right, smugglers transporting a cargo full of *illegal* and rare cargo expect to get paid for at least 50% the market price of the item. While those transporting a cargo with 100 *blaster rifles* (rarity 5, unrestricted, 900 credits each) expect to get paid 4,500 credits (5% of 900 times 100).

Note that the table starts at rarity 4. But that's because goods of rarity 3 or lower are not worth smuggling unless the destination puts higher restriction on the trade of those items, which should increase the item's rarity to something higher than 3.